# Android/Java: Fragment UI not accessible

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In the following minimal example in Java, I'm trying to access widgets that I set in a fragment.  I'm unable to access the widgets. For example, in the below code my calls to `setText()` doesn't work and don't change the layout.

The code compiles, so I don't think I have any issues with my xml.

All the other methods are default, the only methods I changed are `onViewCreated` and `onCreateView`

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    View view;
    Button btn;

    public MyFragment() {}

    @Override
    public void onCreate( ... }

    public static MyFragment newInstance() { ... }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        System.out.println("VIEW CREATED");      // prints

        btn.setText("Text Changed");                     // text isn't changed
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
        btn = view.findViewById(R.id.thisIsAButton);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

I've also tried to set `onClickListeners` and other things to the button, but I just can't access it.

Comment: You need to `return view;` instead from `onCreateView()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with this code

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        System.out.println("VIEW CREATED");      // prints
        btn = view.findViewById(R.id.thisIsAButton);
        btn.setText("Text Changed");                     // text isn't changed
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
        return view;
    }
```